What means Atos SE stock dilution
Lets say I have invested 100euros in ATOS stock on etoro platform.
This message is on internet:

The deal will nevertheless lead to a “massive dilution” of existing shareholders, who are set to hold less than 0.1% of share capital once it is completed, Atos said.

Does it means that I will have only 0.1euro after dilution?

"Dilution" refers to the share of ownership. The value of your shares will remain the same, but will represent 0.1% of the share of ownership you had before the dilution.
This is the news report about the deal. The company is trying to avoid bankruptcy (in which existing shareholders would have probably been wiped out entirely) by selling out to one of its major shareholders through new issue that dilutes everyone else.
It is likely that your initial 100EUR investment is now worth significantly less, but the deal makes it so that it is worth slightly more than 0EUR, which would be the alternative.
I suspect this is done instead of taking the company private and buying you and other shareholders out, in which case you'd have gotten something tangible for your shares. Now, you get to keep your (almost worthless) shares, but your share of ownership is all but eliminated.

I still don't understand i just recently bought the stock.
Lets say I have now 100euros.
Dilution happens. Will I have still +- 100euros or will it be +-0.1 eur?
In other words will I have same number of shares with same value. But I will be less owner of company which is not important for me?

You will have the same number of shares with the same value at the moment of dilution, but 0.1% of the original percentage of the total shares. What the market is going to do about it is undetermined, but it is safe to assume that if the deal goes through the value of the shares will go down to correctly represent the underlying value (of a nearly worthless company).

Okay I get it thank you.
